# Why, when I'm adding two integers, does PHP return a bad result (6+7=1)?

Tags: php, math

I have two variables:

```
$qty = 7;
$_POST['qty'] = 6;

var_dump($qty, $_POST['qty']); // both vars are integers
$_SESSION['qty'] = $qty + $_POST['qty'];
echo '='.$_SESSION['qty'];
```

This returns:

```
int(7) int(6) =1
```

`(int)$qty, (int)$_POST['qty']` doesn't solve the problem.

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

```
... intval($qty) + intval($_POST['qty']);
```

not help.

And I notice one more detail. Problem apeear only when $_SESSION['qty'] >= 10:

```
$_SESSION['qty'] = $qty + $_POST['qty']; // $qty = 3, $_POST['qty'] = 6
```

Return good result ($_SESSION['qty'] = 9).

### **SOLVED**

Thanks all for your unswers. But problem more not actual (it was a server problem). Anyway +1 to all.

Comment: Is your session setup properly?

Comment: Can you show var_dump results for all three variables please?

Comment: What happens if you swap them? And that happens if you put it into another variable (like $temp = $qty + $_POST['qty'];)?

Comment: Daniel, what problem can it be? (Becouse with another variable it work ok).

Comment: Pekka, string(1) "7" string(1) "6" string(1) "1"

Comment: I've copied your code, added <?php and session_start() at the top and I get 13. So I have to assume you're not showing us something.

Comment: I get -> int(7) int(6) =13 ; all clear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your $_SESSION is implicitly initialized as string somewhere

```
$_SESSION = 'blah';

$_SESSION['qty'] = 13;
var_dump($_SESSION['qty']); // gives "1"
```

Comment: This seems to be the case. Make sure you have session_start() at the beginning of your script, and that you aren't assigning the $_SESSION variable (rather than one of its index values) to a string somewhere.

Comment: Good catch. Sometimes answers need a lot of imagination.

Answer (score 1):

Very odd indeed, I've never had this sort of problem. If you explicitly use the integer values in the arithmetic operation? (Not the same as casting to integer)

```
$_SESSION['qty'] = (intval($qty) + intval($_POST['qty']));
```

Have you tried using only your own variables, and leaving the POST-value out of the operation?

Comment: intval() not help... And, problem not in $_POST, tried to do it with test constants without resul.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing with `(int)` is casting the variable, not converting it. You should use `intval($var)` instead.

See [PHP: Integers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting).

Comment: Anyway this give me no results.

Comment: `(int) $x` doesn't change the value of x.

Answer (score 1):

What does this give you?

```
$localQty = 7;
$_POST['qty'] = 6;

$_SESSION['qty'] = ($localQty + $_POST['qty']);
var_dump($_SESSION['qty']);
```

Do you initialize your Session properly with session_start() at the beginning of your script?

Answer (score 1):

I would print_r($_SESSION) to see what it is.